# How to enable masking of mobile numbers using the Uber API?

Tags: uber-api

in the actual Uber app, mobile numbers of the passenger and the driver are masked using a temporary number.

However, we have noticed that while using the Uber API, it seems that real numbers are exposed when requesting a ride and then attempting to call the driver.

Is there any parameter that we can use to enable masking of mobile numbers? We obviously don't want to expose real numbers of either the driver or the passenger.

If not, what is the suggested solution to mask the numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a known issue. Uber will be rolling out a fix soon.

Comment: Update: The feature is being rolled-out to the API city by city. Expect phone numbers to be anonymized world-wide soon.